# Why doesn't QString overload + operator?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, qstring

I've stumbled upon strange behavior when using `operator+` on `QString`s until I found out that `QString` doesn't overload `operator+` (in contrary to `std::string`). What reasons are there not to do it (especially since they overloaded quite a bunch of other operators)?

**Edit: Sorry, I have looked up the wrong section in the docs. Can someone please close the question?**

Comment: But QString does overload operator+, can you describe your issue more.

Comment: What do you mean? There are 5 overloads listed in the docs.

Comment: Just accept an answer below if necessary; the operators are overloaded as non-member functions which is pretty good practice

Comment: Close of question was requested by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does provides the + operator, but the question is what you have at the right hand side?